# How do you detect that a UILabel contains a right-to-left language in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch

I am displaying user comments in two [UILabels](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) - one for the username and one for the message. Both labels have the same X,Y coordinate, but the message label is prepended with spaces equaling the width of the username. This technique helps me easily support multiline messages.

A problem arises when users write Arabic messages. Arabic is a right to left language. This means, I must add spaces to the *end* of an Arabic string, not the beginning. As you can see in the screenshot below, I didn't make that distinction and the Arabic message ran into the username. So how do I detect that the text property ([NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)) of a UILabel was written in a right-to-left language?

[image: arabic]

## Fail attempt 1: Regex

I've tried using [regexes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but the following function always returns false for every string, including Arabic.

```
@implementation UILabel (position)

- (BOOL) containsArabic
{
    NSError* error;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression
        regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\p{Arabic}" 
        options:0
        error:&error
    ];
    return error == nil 
        && [regex 
            numberOfMatchesInString:self.text 
            options:0 
            range:NSMakeRange(0, self.text.length)] > 0;
}

@end
```

## Fail attempt 2: NSLocale

```
- (BOOL) containsArabic
{
    NSString *isoLangCode = (NSString*)CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage(
       (CFStringRef)self.text, 
       CFRangeMake(
           0, 
           self.text.length
       )
    );
    NSLocaleLanguageDirection direction = [NSLocale lineDirectionForLanguage:isoLangCode];
    NSLog(@"++++++");
    NSLog(@"%@", self.text);
    NSLog(@"%d", direction);
    return direction == NSLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft;
}
```

Output is useless:

```
2012-05-28 10:59:11.454 [2110:707] MANCHESTER CITY VS MANCHESTER UNITED LIVE HD
2012-05-28 10:59:11.461 [2110:707] 0
2012-05-28 10:59:11.474 [2110:707] ++++++
2012-05-28 10:59:11.477 [2110:707] tak
2012-05-28 10:59:11.484 [2110:707] 0
2012-05-28 10:59:11.511 [2110:707] ++++++
2012-05-28 10:59:11.513 [2110:707] ŸàŸÜŸáÿßÿ±ŸÉ ÿ≥ÿπŸäÿØ
2012-05-28 10:59:11.520 [2110:707] 3
2012-05-28 10:59:11.704 [2110:707] ++++++
2012-05-28 10:59:11.712 [2110:707] ŸÜŸáÿßÿ±ŸÉ ÿ≥ÿπŸäÿØ
2012-05-28 10:59:11.740 [2110:707] 3
2012-05-28 10:59:11.763 [2110:707] ++++++
2012-05-28 10:59:11.767 [2110:707] i think i am close
2012-05-28 10:59:11.772 [2110:707] 3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer assumes that you are using ARC:

```
NSString *stringToTest = @"Some Foreign Language";

NSString *isoLangCode = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage((__bridge CFStringRef)stringToTest, CFRangeMake(0, stringToTest.length));

NSLocaleLanguageDirection direction = [NSLocale characterDirectionForLangauge:isoLangCode];
```

You can then use the NSLocale API's lineDirectionForLanguage: method to determine the languages line direction.

Comment: That API requires you to pass in the language code. I don't know how to detect the language of a string.

Comment: I added a piece of code that should allow you to determine the users language preference.

Comment: That tells me the preferred language of the viewer of the comment, not the author of the comment. I need the latter, because the authors of the comments write in different languages.

Comment: Ok, I think I finally have my mind wrapped around the question and edited my answer. Sorry for the numerous iterations.

Comment: The `NSLocaleLanguageDirection` returned from `lineDirectionForLanguage` was `3` for both English and Arabic. (Edited my original question with code)

Comment: Try using characterDirectionForLanguage: method. I tested that out and it returns 1 for en and 2 for ar.

Answer (score 1):

In the following function add the following code

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
      NSString *isoLangCode = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage((__bridge CFStringRef)text, CFRangeMake(0, text.length));

      if([isoLangCode isEqualToString:@"ar"])
      {
         //Arabic
      }
      else
      {
         //Other language
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)Direction:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *isoLangCode = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage((__bridge CFStringRef)text, CFRangeMake(0, text.length));

    if([isoLangCode isEqualToString:@"ar"])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```